# phpseclib giving integer too large error only sometimes

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

I'm developing the same app for Android and iOS. Both apps post to a PHP server encrypting parameters using RSA public-private key encryption.

I'm using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) to decrypt requests sent by any of the apps, and until now it has been working great. Usually the mobile app will post only one parameter called data, containing a JSON encrypted with the public key, then, in the server, I decrypt the data parameter using the private key to obtain the JSON data.

But, for one specific service, I need to send two encrypted parameters, the usual encrypted JSON, and a password also encrypted using the same public key. And here is where I cant figure out what's going on. Half the time, both parameters are received with no problem and decrypted returning the correct values, but the rest of the time, I don't get a fatal error, but a user_error in php thrown by the RSA library saying "*Integer too large*". And this returns an empty string. The first parameter "data" is always different because it is encrypted every time, but the password parameter (also encrypted) is always the same, and this is the parameter that only gets unencrypted half the times.

It's really weird, because sometimes it works. And even more weird than that, is what I just tried, I inverted the order in which parameters get unencrypted, password first and then data, and what do you know, no more errors!

This is the class I use to decrypt:

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__) . '/../libs/Crypt');
require_once dirname(__FILE__) .'/../libs/Crypt/Net/SSH2.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../libs/Crypt/Crypt/RSA.php';

class CryptoHandler {

    private $privateKey;

    function __construct() {
        // Load Private Key File
        $this->privateKey = file_get_contents('resources/private_key.pem',FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
    }

    function decrypt($encryptedString) {
        $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
        $rsa->setPassword('password');
        $rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
        $rsa->loadKey($this->privateKey);
        $decryptedString = $rsa->decrypt(base64_decode($encryptedString));

        if (isset($decryptedString) && strlen($decryptedString) > 0){
            return $decryptedString;
        }
        else{
            //This is the exception I get, because $decryptedString's length is 0
            //And also, the integer too large message
            throw new Exception(INVALID_ENCRYPTED_DATA);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

And this is the code that processes the POST request and uses the class:

```
$data = $app->request->post('data');
$encryptedPassword = $app->request->post('password');
try{
    $chdl = new CryptoHandler();
    $parsedRequest = $chdl->decrypt($data);//invert this and the next line and it works
    $password = $chdl->decrypt($encryptedPassword);//$encryptedPassword is always the same
}catch(Exception $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

By the way, I'm using [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) to set paths and give the backend a little structure. 
Thank you for any help you can give me, for now I'll invert the decryption order as it seems to work, but who knows if this will give me trouble in the future.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://pastebin.com/ByjWwUAf I can switch $password and $parsedRequest around just fine without issue. If you're having issues maybe post stand-alone code that can reproduce the problem. ie. provide a key and the values for $data and $encryptedPassword that reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Sadly, it's a little bit difficult to to post code that reproduces the problem, because I make a POST request from an Android or iOS app using a public key. So, there's a lot of code involved. But the weirdest thing, is that if I log the encrypted data to a text file, and the copy the text and use it as a string, the code works fine, every time. So, I don't know what it could be. My guess was that there was a problem allocating memory or something similar, because this only happens when I use the decrypt function two times in a row